# webpack cannot resolve c3.js from Bower: what's wrong?

Tags: webpack, bower

I'm trying to `require("c3");` c3.js chars library with webpack from bower_components, but webpack refuses to do so . I exported many other libraries from bower successfully and can't imagine, what is wrong with this library:

```
require("expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery");
require("metisMenu/dist/metisMenu");
require("iCheck/icheck");
require("expose?_!lodash"); // was underscore
var d3 = require("d3");
```

Those libraries load fine, but this one crashes:

```
var c3 = require("c3");

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'c3' in /home/bob/Documents/...
```

Here's the related piece of webpack.config.js:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    ), // bower; see: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/usage-with-bower
    new ExtractTextPlugin("app.[hash:7].css"),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: "body",
        template: "app/index.html",
        filename: "index.html"
    }),
```

So, loading from bower is set up as recommended and works fine in other cases.

I noticed that `c3` has multiple files in `bower.json` main section:

```
"main": [
  //    "c3.css",
  "c3.js"
],
```

So I commented-out `c3.css` for tests. Still, no good.

What could be the reason of this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [BowerWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin). It should work automatically. If you can not use BowerWebpackPlugin for some reason, you could try this:

```
// webpack.config.js

  resolve: {
      modulesDirectories: ["bower_components"]
  },
  plugins: [
    "..."
  ]
```

And

```
require('c3/c3.css');
var c3 = require('c3/c3.js');
```

Comment: I wonder, how BowerWebpackPlugin is related to ResolverPlugin? The official webpack documentation recommends ResolverPlugin for bower. And BowerWebpackPlugin seems unmaintained for 7 months now.

Comment: BowerWebpackPlugin is not an official plugin. Webpack offers a dependency-resolver tool set, https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/tree/master/lib. You can compose what you need. The problem is not many people understand how to use the tool set and there is no example for bower-multiple-main-target case.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I managed to require `c3` as a file, not as a bower package. Just said `require('c3/c3');`.

I really don't know, what was the reason of this behavior - but not multiple `main` targets in c3's `bower.json`.